# creating session for simple php password

Tags: php, session, passwords

I need to be able to store the password submitted in a session, as at present using the php_self method the page is just reloading as if the user has not entered the password correctly (this is happening in Firefox, it actually works fine with no session in Chrome / Safari) and so I believe a session is needed for it to work in FF, but I'm newish to PHP and not sure how I can go about this, here's the code:

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
session_start();

$Password = 'hello';

   if (isset($_POST['submit_pwd'])){
      $pass = isset($_POST['passwd']) ? $_POST['passwd'] : '';


      if ($pass != $Password) {
         showForm("error", "WRONG PASSWORD");
         exit();     
      }
   } else {
      showForm();
      exit();
   }

function showForm($Inputclass="mister", $Placeholder="PLEASE ENTER PASSWORD"){ 

?>
```

With HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="pwd" id="pwd">


 <input class="<?php echo $Inputclass; ?>" name="passwd" type="password" size="79" style="margin-left: -100px;" placeholder="<?php echo $Placeholder; ?>"/>
         <br/>
             <input class="text" name="submit_pwd" value="Login" type="image" src="loginkey.png" style="position: relative; left: 240px; top: -35px;">

      </form>
```

Comment: And you are sure this is the safest way you can imagine?

Comment: Server-side code is browser-independent. If it works in Chrome and not Firefox, your issue is not with PHP.

Comment: I am aware I should be using hashes, salts, etc - this is a really simple project so I just need a basic password, but I need it to work across browsers

Comment: bad idea, make them refill every time

Comment: Thanks both - any ideas why the FF version is just refreshing? I thought it was to do with the way it stored cookies potentially

Comment: use tamper-data plugin for FF in order to check that the form parameters are submitted

Comment: Firefox caching is a little too aggressive. That could be the problem. Try calling your page using some unique random query string. **Way to check:** Clear cache, load your initial page as `http://xyz.com/login.php?q=0`, and then carry out a login attempt.

Comment: When you output your $_POST, what do you get in FF? e.g. var_dump($_POST);

Comment: DarkXphenomenon - I used your method and it takes a little longer to think.. and then refreshes as normal, what does that mean?

Comment: See answer - it's a submit image, not a submit button and they behave differently in different browsers (IE, Chrome and FF all behave differently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hit the button, then $_POST['submit_pwd_x'] and $_POST['submit_pwd_y'] should be set, not $_POST['submit_pwd']

If you hit "enter" then $_POST['submit_pwd'], $_POST['submit_pwd_x'] or $_POST['submit_pwd_y'] should NOT be set - but sometimes are depending on the browser.

You can't rely on either, so your check if (isset($_POST['submit_pwd']))  will be unreliable

The trick is to add a hidden field in the form, and check for sbmission of that hidden field in $_POST.

---

More details on the answer (based on comment):

PHP is

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])){ 
    ....
}
```

HTML is

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="pwd" id="pwd"> 
     <input class="<?php echo $Inputclass; ?>" name="passwd" type="password" size="79" style="margin-left: -100px;" placeholder="<?php echo $Placeholder; ?>"/> 
     <br/>
     <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="1" /> 
     <input class="text" name="submit_pwd" value="Login" type="image" src="loginkey.png" style="position: relative; left: 240px; top: -35px;"> 

</form>
```

---

Edit:

If you don't click on the button (hit enter):

- IE will send none
- FF,Opera will send the submit_pwd_x=0 and submit_pwd_y=0
- Chrome,Safari will send the submit_pwd_x=0, submit_pwd_y=0 and submit_pwd

If you click the button:

- IE will send submit_pwd_x=X and submit_pwd_y=Y
- FF,Opera will send submit_pwd_x=X and submit_pwd_y=Y
- Chrome,Safari will send the submit_pwd_x=X, submit_pwd_y=Y and submit_pwd

Comment: Thanks Robbie - that all makes sense. So I need FF to submit all three, or you're saying that's not possible and this script simply won't work?

Comment: Thanks Robbie - I changed to using <button> tags with an image in the middle... and it works! Thanks very much